# How to adjust Brave browser's address bar to increase its size?

Tags: lubuntu, brave

I have not been able to find out how to make BRAVE browser's address bar bigger.

Currently it's very small. Increasing the size of fonts doesn't increase the size of the address bar font.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You haven't provided release details... eg. which desktop are you using?  Lubuntu narrows it down somewhat, but we still need release details.  Also details on where you changed fonts may also help (eg. was it as per https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.2/appearance.html?highlight=fonts or something different?; I've assumed modern (*LXQt*) Lubuntu with that link over legacy (*LXDE*))

Answer (score 1):

In Brave, use the Hamburger menu top right and select `Settings`.

In Settings > Appearance select Use wide address bar.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't change the size of the font in the address bar or the font size of tab titles and bookmark titles around the address bar either. It all looks too small in Ubuntu mate 20.04.1 whereas it looks OK in Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add scaling factor to how brave is being launched each time.
Find this file:

```
 /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
```

inside it search for

```
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U
```

change it to

```
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --force-device-scale-factor=n %U
```

where n is the scaling factor

TIP:

Best way to find files is to :

```
sudo apt install locate
```

then

```
sudo updatedb
```

and
finally

```
locate filename
```